# what is your favorite third party API for Google maps V3 ??? and why?

Tags: performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

I need from you to share your experience with any third party API for Google Maps V3 and your rating 
please share information like

name , url , tech used (serverside , clientside ) , price or license  , performance , any thing you would like to add

for example I like:

1-markermanager

2-http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html

3-javascript

4-free

5-it had very good performance

these information might be very handy for any developer

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) out there.

I personally have used

[keydragzoom](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/),javascript,free,good performance

Comment: Thanks Argiropoulos for ykeydragzoom , i wasn't know about it